# Как переслать анимацию кубика другому пользователю?

Tags: python, aiogram

Мне нужно пересылать кубик другому пользователю в бота, дабы он видел какое значение выпало у опонента. Очень сильно нуждаюсь в вашей помощи, т.к незнаю как это реализовать.

Заметил, что если переслать сообщения с кубиком, то результаты сохряняються, только вот реализовать это в коде не могу).

```
@dp.callback_query(F.data.startswith('join_room_'))
async def join_room_callback(callback: CallbackQuery):
    try:
        
        
        callback_data = callback.data
        room_user_id = callback_data.split('_')[2]  # Получаем room_user_id из callback_data
        # Извлекаем идентификатор комнаты из данных колбэка
        
        opponent_name = callback.message.chat.first_name
        opponent_id = callback.from_user.id
        # Ваш код для присоединения к комнате по room_id
        
        join_room_db(room_user_id, opponent_id, opponent_name)
        # Получите идентификатор создателя комнаты
        
        user_info_id = get_creator_id(room_user_id)
        creator_info_id = user_info_id['creator_id']
        creator_user_name = user_info_id['creator_name']
        opponent_info_id = user_info_id['opponent_id']
        opponent_user_name = user_info_id['opponent_name']
        bet_amount = user_info_id['bet_amount']

        await bot.send_message(creator_info_id, f'You dropping', parse_mode='Markdown')
        bot_data_creator_first = await callback.bot.send_dice(creator_info_id)
        bot_data_creator_first = int(bot_data_creator_first.dice.value)
 
        await bot.send_message(opponent_info_id, bot_data_creator_first) # тут мне нужно переслать этот кубик другому пользователю
```